# What encryption to use for good performance?

Tags: linux, encryption

I will install Ubuntu 11.04 to an [encrypted VolumeGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsSBP.png) with the installer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skil9.png

AES
Blowfish
Serpent

Which one is the fastest from these 3? Or Using AES with [only a 128 bit key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPVa6.png) gives the best performance/speed? Does someone has a graph/statistics about them? (or e.g.: what is the performance/speed difference between using an encrypted VG or not using encryption at all.)

If there aren't any statistics about this, then how could I do one? What tests are there on the "market"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This table](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html) shows that AES with 128 bit keys would be faster.  In fact, even with 256 bit keys it'd be faster.  (of course, a comparison chart for the exact implementation would be better).

That being said, since it's such a popular algorithm I'd be tempted to pick it based on popularity because it's something you're going to want around and well supported.  I'm sure the other two will be too, but I'm *more* sure that AES will be.

Comment: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/AES_instruction_set